# How to allow null value on serializer when the field in the model is required?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Given the following `payload`, `models.py`, and `serializers.py` in Django (DRF):

`payload`

```
{
  "created_by": 6,
  "brand": 1,
  "foo_details": [
    {
      "quantity": 123,
      "price_estimation": 456
    },
    {
      "quantity": 789,
      "price_estimation": 1011
    }
  ]
}
```

`models.py`

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # OTHER FIELDS HERE

class FooChild(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="foo_details")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    price_estimation = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    # OTHER FIELDS HERE
```

`serializers.py`

```
class FooChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # foo = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, required=False) -> LINE 2

    class Meta:
        model = FooChild
        fields = ["id", "foo", "quantity", "price_estimation", ...]

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # foo_details = FooChildSerializer(many=True) -> LINE 9
    # foo_details = serializers.DictField(child=serializers.CharField(), many=True) -> LINE 10

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ["id", "created_by", "brand", "foo_details", ...]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # I want to save the payload to `Foo` and `FooChild` inside this function at the same time, below is my unsuccessful attempt

        # print(validated_data)
        # validated_data.pop("foo_details")
        # foo = Foo.objects.create(**validated_data) -> LINE 21
        # foo_child = FooChild.objects.create(foo=foo)
        
        # return foo
```

The problem I'm having right now is, when I tried to POST the payload, DRF complained that `foo` field in `FooChild` is required, which is understandable, the problem is, the `id` of the `Foo` exists only after I created the `foo` instance (on line 21). I tried to tell DRF to ignore the requirement to provide `foo` when creating `FooChild` to no avail (see line 2, 9, 10 above). How do I solve this problem?

Actually I have an idea to set `null=True` in the `FooChild` model, but the `FooChild` can't exist without `Foo`, so I figured this doesn't make any sense. Thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a null value on the `foo` field in the `FooChild` serializer while keeping the field as required in the model, you can modify your code as follows:

1. In `FooChildSerializer`, remove the `foo` field declaration.

```
class FooChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FooChild
        fields = ["id", "quantity", "price_estimation", ...]
```

2. In `FooSerializer`, update the `foo_details` field to handle the creation of `FooChild` instances after saving the `Foo` instance.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo_details = FooChildSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ["id", "created_by", "brand", "foo_details", ...]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        foo_details_data = validated_data.pop("foo_details", None)

        foo = Foo.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if foo_details_data:
            for foo_detail_data in foo_details_data:
                FooChild.objects.create(foo=foo, **foo_detail_data)

        return foo
```

By setting `required=False` for the `foo_details` field in the serializer, it allows the field to be optional in the payload. In the `create` method, we extract the `foo_details` data from `validated_data` using `pop`, keeping it `None` if not present.

After creating the `foo` instance, we check if `foo_details_data` exists. If it does, we iterate over the data and create `FooChild` instances, associating them with the `foo` instance.

This way, you can create a `Foo` instance with or without providing `foo_details` in the payload. If `foo_details` are provided, they will be associated with the `Foo` instance after it is created.

Comment: aw, it was so simple, yet I completely missed it. Thx for the answer, you were a great help